# How to handle request methods in function based views in Django

Tags: python, django

As I am learning Django I have some questions about the handling of request methods for *function based views* (FBVs) in Django.

#### What I found for FBVs:

> The URLconf doesn’t look at the request method. In other words, all request methods – POST, GET, HEAD, etc. – will be routed to the same function for the same URL.

from [URL-Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/).

> require_http_methods(request_method_list)¶
> Decorator to require that a view only accepts particular request methods

from [View Decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/decorators/)

Does that mean, I can restrict an `URL` defined in `urls.py` to a function which in turn only accepts say `PUT`-Requests and in case I want to handle `DELETE` said `URL` is wasted, since I restricted it to `PUT`?

Or otherwise, I have to "dispatch" myself within the FBV?

E.g. with [request.method == 'PUT'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method)

---

#### Alternatively for CBVs

> Organization of code related to specific HTTP methods (GET, POST, etc.) can be addressed by separate methods instead of conditional branching.

from [Introduction to class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/)

---

#### Does that mean, if I want to handle `PUT` or `DELETE` in separate functions I have to

a) use a class based view with the verbs being implemented like `put()` and `delete()`

b) use DjangoResteFramework only for having  [APIViews](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) and `@api_view(['Put'])` as a decorator for FBVs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal FBV. I think this is not good in Django, but you can:

```
def myFunctionView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    match request.method:
        case "GET":
            # do some stuff
            return response_for_get
        case "DELETE":
            # do some stuff
            return response_for_delete
        case "PATCH":
            # do some stuff
            return response_for_path
        case _: # post, put, option e.t.c
            # do some stuff
            return response_for_post
```

It is completely against Django Philosophy, but it is possible. You can made an decorator to send "method not allowed" status for some request.methods. you can use this decorator in urls.py. But i don't understand, why you want to avoid the GCBV, best part of Django views.

Comment: I read some of the stuff from https://spookylukey.github.io/django-views-the-right-way/ and I think the author has a valid point. I have come over the years to the conclusion that inheritance may be a good idea but has a lot of pitfalls mainly it abstracts away too many things. Debugging a function is easier than an inheritance tree, god beware of several mixins lurking somewhere. Perhaps when it is against Django philosophy, Django is no good fit for my needs :)

Comment: Or to put it in other words, when I write a monolith doing trad Forms on the one hand and doing "API"-stuff like sending simple JSON over the wire or receiving JSON, these are two separate concerns where Django fits the first and DRF the second?

Comment: in your case, if you do simple things in simple way - you don't need any django. Try to see Robyn github.com/sansyrox/robyn or sanic  sanic.dev/en/ or fastapi fastapi.tiangolo.com or BlackSheep github.com/Neoteroi/BlackSheep. They all about easy and fastest waty to do simple things,

Comment: Deep in Django internal layers you meet only inheritance, Metaclasses, decorators, tears and pain. Luke Plant is wrong with own "right way". He is wrong with Django. Its like use Catepillar Digger in sport rally. It is possible... but it's stupid.

Answer (score 0):

In you views.

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only GET or POST requests make it this far
    # ...
    pass
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods